# filter textView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i`m building an iPhone app , in the app i upload images to a server, i get the result from this code

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

and it shows up like this

=======

http://www.mylink.com/30268.jpg

121084

application/octet-stream

.jpg

./30268.jpg

=======

what i need is to insert just the url "http://www.mylink.com/30268.jpg" into a text label

i searched for a way but with no luck

any ideas ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the parts of the string are separated by line breaks, so you could try [[returnString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: it didn`t work when i changed it to atIndex:1 to get the second line

Comment: That's strange.  What happens if you log the length of returnString?  And, what do you mean by it didn't work?  What result did you get?  Did you get an error message?

Comment: the result was empty , nothing been logged , when it was at atIndex:0 it logged the first line

Comment: It sounds like there's nothing else in that string then.  Did you try logging the returnString's length?  In your original post, you said you wanted the first line -- do you want to get the other lines as well?